# Flask-Migrate no padrão Factory - Erro app not found

Tags: python, flask, factory

Olá,

Estou tentando rodar o comando: `flask db init`, porém o traceback retorna:

[image: traceback:]

main/app/extensions/migrate.py:

```py
from flask_migrate import Migrate
from main.extensions.sqlalchemy import db

migrate = Migrate()


def init_app(app):
    migrate.init_app(app, db)
```

main/app/extensions/dynaconf.py:

```py
from importlib import import_module
from dynaconf import FlaskDynaconf


def load_extensions(app):
    for extension in app.config.get('EXTENSIONS'):
        module = import_module(extension)
        module.init_app(app)


def init_app(app):
    FlaskDynaconf(app)
```

main/app/app.py:

```py
from flask import Flask
from main.extensions import dynaconf

_SECRET_KEY = None


def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    dynaconf.init_app(app)
    dynaconf.load_extensions(app)
    _SECRET_KEY = app.config.get('SECRET_KEY')

    return app
```

Answer (score 0):

Você está esquecendo de importar o app nos arquivos "main/app/extensions/migrate.py" e "main/app/extensions/dynaconf.py"

na primeira linha de ambos você coloca

```
from app import app
```

Comment: Não rola, se eu fizer isso vai rolar Circular Import e a execução para. A função load_extensions inicializa todos os módulos dentro de app.

Comment: você tambem esta programando no estilo que o orientado objeto só que em linguagem estruturada, o flask é orientado ao objeto, pode utilizar a crianção de classes para ter recursos como construtor, que você fez em init_app